# How to avoid windows zoom in electron app

Tags: electron

If the Windows display zoom is set to 150%, the Electron app also appears zoomed. I want my app to avoid the windows zoom level and always display in 100% zoom only.

I have tried the `zoomFactor:1` but it's not working.

[image]

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/6571#issuecomment-326865765

Answer (score 8):

As per [@hijleh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9698583/hijleh) suggestion, adding the following lines in the main process has resolved the issue. The app is now avoiding the Windows display zoom.

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('high-dpi-support', 1)
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('force-device-scale-factor', 1)
```

Comment: For those who previously zoomed out/in of the application before the above fix and need to reset it: The file structure should be ```C:\Users\%YOUR-USER%\AppData\Roaming\%YOUR-APP%\```, edit the ```Preferences``` file with an editor (I used notepad), look for ```{per_host_zoom_levels": {"%SOME-NUMBER%":{%HERE%}}}```. At the ```%HERE%``` part will have the zoom preference, delete the contents to reset and so that ```{per_host_zoom_levels": {"%SOME-NUMBER%":{}}}``` remains. Can augment to have different values as well. Hope it helps for future readers!